# Store User Pictures locally in android app and transfer them when the user changes device

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i am developing an Android app where I need to store some user pictures. Is there an easy way to do this locally and where they get transferred to a new phone in case of an "upgrade" (so when the user changes to a new device)?

I don't want you to use cloud options for this as I'm not interested in paying for this at the moment.

Is there a way like a folder within the Android gallery?
(I am thinking of data transfer with Smart Switch)

I am developing in Kotlin.

Comment: It would be best to try adding a P2P data transfer feature to your app. Check the android-developers-guides related to p2p data transfer and devise a strategy that suits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use SD card to save data in this case